# UICollectionviewcell with AVPlayerLayer play only ten videos after that give error

Tags: ios, video, avplayer, avplayerlayer

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        if (cell.videoLayer) {
                            [cell.videoLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
                        }
                        cell.videoPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:cell.videoItem];
                        cell.videoLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:cell.videoPlayer];
                        cell.videoLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
                        cell.videoPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
                        cell.videoLayer.frame = cell.videoPlayerContainer.bounds;
                        [cell.videoPlayerContainer.layer addSublayer:cell.videoLayer];
                        cell.videoPlayer.volume = 0.0;
                        NSLog(@"Video Play at index: %ld", (long)indexPath.row);

                        [cell.videoItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playbackBufferEmpty" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial context:nil];
                        [cell.videoItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playbackLikelyToKeepUp" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial context:nil];
                        [cell.videoPlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"currentItem.status" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:kStatusDidChangeKVO];

                        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                                 selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                                                     name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                                                   object:[cell.videoPlayer currentItem]];

                        [cell.videoPlayer play];
                    });
```

here is my cellForItemAtIndexPath code